# implementing Linkedin Oauth sign up with rails Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, linkedin-api

Here is my Controller that handles the callback:

```
class OauthController < ApplicationController
  def callback
    begin
      oauth = OauthService.new(request.env['omniauth.auth'])
      if oauth_account = oauth.create_oauth_account!
          @user = User.from_omniauth(oauth)
          sign_in_as(@user)
          redirect_to root
      else
        redirect_to new_user_registration_path
      end
    rescue => e
      flash[:alert] = "There was an error while trying to authenticate your account."
      redirect_to new_user_registration_path
    end
  end

  def failure
    flash[:alert] = "There was an error while trying to authenticate your account."
    redirect_to new_user_registration_path
  end

  protected

  private
  def user_params
    params.permit(:email, :password)
  end
end
```

And the service that it runs on:

```
class OauthService
  attr_reader :auth_hash

  def initialize(auth_hash)
    @auth_hash = auth_hash
  end

  def create_oauth_account!
    unless oauth_account = OauthAccount.where(uid: @auth_hash[:uid]).first
      oauth_account = OauthAccount.create!(oauth_account_params)
    end
  end

private

  def oauth_account_params
    { uid: @auth_hash[:uid],
      provider: @auth_hash[:provider],
      image_url: @auth_hash[:info][:image],
      profile_url: @auth_hash[:info][:urls][:public_profile],
      raw_data: @auth_hash[:extra][:raw_info].to_json }
  end

end
```

I can't seem to work out why the browser manages to redirect to linkedin, work over there and return only to be forwarded to my sign_up_page.

There must be something . wrong with the `if oauth_account = oath.create_oauth_account!` or the line before it.

I'm following a few tutorials and this is as far as I've gotten from any of them authenticating with LinkedIn, using Omni Oauth 2.

If I change the second redirect_to new_user_registration_path to redirect_to root it shows an error with .from_omniauth(oauth), no defined method.

But here in my user.rb:

```
def from_omniauth(auth_hash)
    user = find_or_create_by(uid: auth_hash['uid'], provider: auth_hash['provider'])
    user.user_id = auth_hash['uid']
    user.username = auth_hash['info']['name']
    user.location = get_social_location_for user.provider, auth_hash['info']['location']
    user.image_url = auth_hash['info']['image']
    user.url = get_social_url_for user.provider, auth_hash['info']['urls']
    user.save!

    filename =user.user_id + user.username
    File.open(filename, "w+") do |f|
      f.write(oauth['extra']['raw_info'])
    end
    user
  end
```

You can see it's defined properly and has an extra to attempt to find out order or the extra raw_info json block.

Comment: Any specific reason you're not using this gem https://github.com/decioferreira/omniauth-linkedin-oauth2

Comment: I've been trying to implement at least one of those, yes. I've followed 5 tutorials that run into errors and stop.

Not quite sure how to fully implement this gem.